# You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysqli, mysql

Столкнулся со следующей ошибкой

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update toyshop_product set price=738 where sku like ('1109507') limit 1; update' at line 2<br />Error No: 1064<br />update toyshop_product set price=624 where sku like ('1114612') limit 1; update toyshop_product set price=738 where sku like ('1109507') limit 1; update toyshop_product set price=957 where sku like ('1118691') limit 1; update toyshop_product set price=2738 where sku like ('1110266') limit 1; update toyshop_product set price=1863 where sku like ('1131626') limit 1; update toyshop_product set price=2113 where sku like ('1131628') limit 1; update toyshop_product set price=4938 where sku like ('1131627') limit 1; update toyshop_product set price=312 where sku like ('1110346') limit 1; update toyshop_product set price=319 where sku like ('1110355') limit 1; update toyshop_product set price=349 where s in

Есть php код который генерирует запросы.

```
        $margin = $this->config->get('margin');
    $rate_margins = floatval($margin)/100+1;
    $q = array();
    foreach($goods as $itm)
    {
        $newPrice = ceil(floatval($itm[10])*$rate_margins);
        $q[] ="update " . DB_PREFIX . "product set price={$newPrice}  where sku like ('{$itm[3]}') limit 1;";
    }
    $sql = implode("\n", $q);

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Если вардампить запрос, и выполнить его в heidiSQL то все ок, все работает, если совершать запросы прямо в цикле, то все тоже ок. А вот при раскладе выше - фатал, в чем проблема никак не пойму.

PS. часть дампа запросов

> update toyshop_product set price=624 
> where sku like ('1114612') limit 1;
>
> update toyshop_product set price=738 
> where sku like ('1109507') limit 1;
>
> update toyshop_product set price=957 
> where sku like ('1118691') limit 1;

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить 1, а не весь массив запросов.

Comment: Как предположение, тк не обладаю точной инфой по этому вопросу: а вы уверены, что MySQL понимает такие склеенные символом новой строки запросы?

Comment: @MDJHD, +1, например Workbench дает выполнить только один запрос в пакете

Comment: @ICE Один запрос проходит.
@MDJHD Пробовал и с переносом строки, и без него, результат один.
PS запросы выполняю через mysqli->query();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну здесь, если смотреть по выдаваемому описанию ошибки

> update toyshop_product set price=738 where sku like ('1109507') limit 1; update

Ошибка возникает на втором `update`, то есть Mysql не понимает таких запросов. Прогоняйте по одному запросу в цикле. Для увеличения быстродействия ройте в сторону prepare-запросов